'RivePlugin' has different definitions in different modules flutter
Got this error message when run app in flutter, using IOS simulator:
Error (Xcode):
'RivePlugin' has different definitions in different modules; first difference is definition in module 'rive_common.Swift' found method
/Users/rafaelvazquez/Documents/app/aloha_makeup/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/rive_common/rive_common.framework/Headers/rive_common-Swift.h:309:0

Modules Issue (Xcode):
Definition of 'RivePlugin' must be imported from module 'rive_common.Swift' before it is required
/Users/rafaelvazquez/Documents/app/aloha_makeup/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:113:3

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 16 Plus.

It's quite frustrating that there is not even a single answer here considering that my app's visuals heavily depend on rive animations including buttons menus etc. I hope they get it fixed soon because I won't be able to launch without this, I am imagining the horrors of reproducing my app with a different animation engine. I hope they get it fixed soon.

@SuperCode update your rive plugin version and that should be ok.
I explained it in this answer https://github.com/rive-app/rive-flutter/issues/439#issuecomment-2565040515
